# How to support ManyTableToManyTable by relationship with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Now I have some tables come from a 3rd software.

```
class A:
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class B:
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class C:
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class Link:
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    src_id = Column(Integer)
    src_type = Column(String)  # such as 'A', 'B', 'C'
    dst_id = Column(Integer)
    dst_type = Column(String)  # such as 'A', 'B', 'C'
```

So how can I pass params to relationship to support this structure? Now my temporary solution is:

```
class Link:
    ...
    src_a = relationship(A, foreign_keys=[src_id, src_type], primary_join=(src_type=='A') & (src_id = A.id))
    src_b = relationship(B, foreign_keys=[src_id, src_type], primary_join=(src_type=='B') & (src_id = B.id))
    src_c = relationship(C, foreign_keys=[src_id, src_type], primary_join=(src_type=='C') & (src_id = C.id))
    dst_a = relationship(A, foreign_keys=[dst_id, dst_type], primary_join=(dst_type=='A') & (dst_id = A.id))
    dst_b = relationship(B, foreign_keys=[dst_id, dst_type], primary_join=(dst_type=='B') & (dst_id = B.id))
    dst_c = relationship(C, foreign_keys=[dst_id, dst_type], primary_join=(dst_type=='C') & (dst_id = C.id))

session.query(A, B).join(Link, Link.src_a.expression).join(B, Link.dst_b.expression)
```

But yes, this is unmaintainable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks just like the [Generic relationship](https://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generic_relationship.html) of `sqlalchemy_utils`, with which you can have:

```
from sqlalchemy_utils import generic_relationship

class Link:
    ...
    src = generic_relationship(src_type, src_id)
    dst = generic_relationship(dst_type, dst_id)
```

Comment: Can generic_relationship use a simple join clause? Like `A.join(Link).join(B)` or `A.join(Link, Link.src).join(B, Link.dst)`?

Comment: Never tried that, but I'm afraid it may not work. Would [this](https://github.com/kvesteri/sqlalchemy-utils/issues/52) help?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with such joins? Loading all links with A as src and B as dest?

Comment: OK, I read the source code. It doesn't support join clause and backref. I think generic_relationship can't meet all my needs, but it is the nearest one. I will try to extend it.

Comment: Yes. Actually I have some people and some tasks linked by these structure, I want to join them and find some people with their tasks.

Comment: Okay then, glad it helped.